# How can I improve waterproof flooring for outdoor landing?

Tags: waterproofing, landing

I have an outdoor landing outside our back door that is mostly covered by roof overhang (~90% covered). It consists of 3/4" plywood covered with paint, with metal edging at the edge of the landing attached to the plywood with screws.

There's an area where the landing meets the house siding where the paint has peeled back, and this area just leaked rainwater into the basement today.

I'm planning on scraping away the existing paint, sanding the plywood, and removing any areas of rot (if there are any). For restaining or repainting the plywood - I'm looking for suggestions for waterproof and durable options.

[image: outdoor landing partially covered by roof]

[image: metal edging]

[image: area where rain leaked into basement below]

Comment: Flashing. You'll want flashing. Either metal or rubber membrane or maybe both.

Comment: Thanks @FreeMan! To clarify - if I install flashing along the edge where the landing meets the blue siding, I need to tuck the flashing behind the siding shingles, right?

Comment: @EliKern correct. The alternative is liberal sealant at the top edge of the flashing, which will look worse, be less effective, and may not last very long depending on the weather you experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to install flashing (metal, self-adhesive rubber membrane, other) *under* the siding on the wall and over the top surface of the landing. This will keep water from running between the wall and the landing.

This should, of course, have been done *before* the siding was installed. It may well have been done with lower quality materials that have since failed.

You'll also want to ensure that your porch floor has proper slope to ensure that any water that does end up here runs out, away from the walls and off the edge.

---

#### Additional note:

That metal cap over the edge of the plywood floor will protect the edge from damage (foot falls, bike tires, etc.) but it is acting as a dam, holding water in. Even though the metal is thin, it's going to be holding water on top of the plywood, causing both it and the walls to fail faster. Not sure that I've got a good, quick answer for addressing that, but I'd suggest a whole new question here to ask about how to better protect that.